# How to map our application to latest versioned dll in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application which used classlibrary.dll which is in GAC . Now I update my classlibrary.dll with new  version and installed it in   GAC again(side  by side execution) .

I want my application to refer new version of classlibrary.dll without rebuilding it, how can i do this.

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Redirecting Assembly Versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)